# Certutil in CentOS complaining of an incorrect password

Tags: centos, certutil

I just setup a minimum Centos 7 and ran `pwgen` and tried to create a new database. It complains that it is the incorrect password.

These are my commands:

```
# pwgen -sy 32 1 > /etc/openldap/certs/password
# certutil -d /etc/openldap/certs -N -f /etc/openldap/certs/password
```

and this the password inside `/etc/openldap/certs/password`:

```
.ha?nB0WU.D.Lx3*kmw?z7rbZoAMdJ"B
```

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Please add to the body of the question the error verbatim.

Comment: Invalid password.  That is all I get.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what the problem was. It is looking for an empty directory to create the database so the initial pwgen generation should be else where, like tmp/password. That got rid of the problem. Thanks for the views and feed backs.